# Html circular symbols are missing when print button is clicked

Tags: php, html, css

i need to make small circles around digits to make a OMR sheet
For this I have used the following css style

```
  //.................
.numberCircle {
border-radius: 100%;
behavior: url(PIE.htc); /* remove if you don't care about IE8 */

width: 10px;
height: 1px;
padding: 1px;

background: #fff;
border: 2px solid #000000;
color: #666;
text-align: center;

font: 8px Arial, sans-serif;
}
//......................

 echo "<a class='numberCircle'>4</a>";
```

Everything is working fine. But the problem is that when I click the print button, the circles are disappearing from the output.

How to fix it?

For printing I have used

```
 <input type="button" onclick="document.title= ss;  window.print();"  id="printbtn" value="Print" style="font-size:2.5ex;" />
```

Comment: What are you using to print? Browser menu? Own code?

Comment: <input type="button" onclick="document.title= ss;  window.print();" id="printbtn" value="Print" style="font-size:2.5ex;" />

Comment: This is helpful, please add this code to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I added below code to css, it looks better.

```
display: inline-block;
height: 10px;
```

Additionally, if you aim to print something, use `pt` as font-size instead of `px`,

Below blog say `pt` are traditionally used in print media.

Refer to the blog [CSS Font-Size: em vs. px vs. pt vs. percent](http://kyleschaeffer.com/development/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/)

Check it your print setting that background graphics is on

[image]

Comment: The circles are visible after adding the above two lines to css. A minor problem still persists. Of the circles I have made few with dark background  (as it is done for the right answers in OMR sheet). But the dark backgrounds are still missing in the output. All are visible with transparent backgrounds.

Comment: Ya now I am achieved my target by making the background graphics checked. Thanks